# cassandra-driver: ImportError: No module named queue

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

I'm installing cassandra-driver with pip on OSX 10.11.
Straight out of pip, cassandra-driver gives this error:

```
traceback (most recent call last):   File "syncS3ToCassandra.py", line 19, in <module>
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster   File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 48, in init cassandra.cluster (cassandra/cluster.c:74747)   
File "cassandra/connection.py", line 38, in init cassandra.connection (cassandra/connection.c:28007) 
ImportError: No module named queue
```

I haven't tried building cassandra-driver from source but pip is the recommended method. Here's my code:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.policies import DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy

cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect('foo')
```

Comment: Seems that OSX 10.11 comes with six 1.4.1 pre-installed and installing six with pip will not update the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by updating my ~/.profile with:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

and installing python-2.7.11

```
$ brew install python
```

Then restarting my shell.

Answer (score 5):

I also meet this issue on my mbp. And there are some other problems that I can't uninstall six. I use easy_install to update version from 1.4.1 to 1.10.0 to fix it.

```
$sudo easy_install -U six
```

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

From the source code, you need the package **six** to be installed and it should have a subpackage **moves** which contains a module **queue.py**:

```
38    from six.moves.queue import Queue, Empty
```

Can you try to reinstall six?

1. pip uninstall six
2. pip install six

Comment: It appears there's something fishy with six, I reinstalled it and got version 1.10 on pip, but running python -c "import six; print six.__version__"
gives me version 1.4.1.

Comment: smells bad, indeed

Comment: Facing the same problem and seeing the same six version difference (1.4.1 vs 1.10 from pip).. any more advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

Since **cassandra-driver** (version 3.4.1) is only available as `.tar.gz` package, you have to recompile it from the sources. This is what pip do.

I successfully install it on OSX 10.11.5 (it took at least one minute to compile).

I try this:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
>>> from cassandra.policies import DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy
>>> cluster = Cluster()
>>> session = cluster.connect('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

The last error is normal because I don't have the server.

**EDIT: Installation in Python 3.5**

I successfully installed and tested (as much as I can) this driver in Python 3.5.1 on OSX 10.11.5

```
$ python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
>>> from cassandra.policies import DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy
>>> cluster = Cluster()
>>> session = cluster.connect('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers'[..])
```

I have created a virtualenv using base prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5'.

Comment: Anything special about how you installed it? With/out cython or libev?

Comment: Well, when I upgraded to El Capitan, I needed to install XCode Command Line Tools. The Command Line Tools Package is a small self-contained package available for download separately from Xcode and that allows you to do command line development in OS X. See my version of GCC. Note: I tried with Python 2.